# Throwing a generic Exception as the original exception type

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to perform the same task against a few different servers. If one of the calls is successful, then the who task should be successful. However, if every call fails, I want to throw up the latest exception that was thrown (as it's likely the same error across the others). Is this possible?

Here is what I am working with:

```
public void doSomething()
{
  boolean success = false;
  Exception failureException;

  for(Server server : Servers.values())
  {
    try{
      doSomethingToServer(server);
      success = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      failureException = e;
      log("failure reason");
    }
  }

  if(!success){
    //throw failureException as its original type
  }
}
```

Rather than throw up the original exception as type "Exception" I want to throw it up as the type it originally was. Is this possible?

Comment: *"I want to throw up **the** original exception"* There is no single original exception. There are `Servers.size()` exceptions. None of them are more or better than the others. They may all be different too. So, which one would you consider to be **the** original exception?

Comment: `throw failureException`? You haven't actually changed the exception by catching it as `Exception`.

Comment: @Andreas, the latest exception is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "the original exception" you mean the *first* exception, you do it like this.

```
public void doSomething() throws Exception {
    boolean success = false;
    Exception failureException = null;
    for (Server server : Servers.values()) {
        try {
            doSomethingToServer(server);
            success = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (failureException == null)
                failureException = e;
            else
                failureException.addSuppressed(e);
        }
    }
    if (! success && failureException != null)
        throw failureException;
}
```

Added code to add secondary exceptions as [*suppressed exceptions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), and null check in case `Servers` is empty, i.e. `success` is false but no errors occurred.

And of course added `throws Exception` to the method, so it compiles.

---

**UPDATE**

Now, if `doSomethingToServer()` throw checked exception(s), and you want `doSomething()` to throw the same checked exception(s), not a blanket catch-all `Exception`, then you capture the exception as before, but have to cast to the appropriate exception(s) when re-throwing it.

To help keep cast statements in sync with what `doSomethingToServer()` can actually throw, it's best to change the `catch` clause to be more explicit. That way, if someone adds a new checked exception, they *must* modify the `catch` clause, and that hopefully triggers them to remember to add a new `if-then-cast` statement.

```
public void doSomething() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    boolean success = false;
    Exception failureException = null;
    for (Server server : Servers.values()) {
        try {
            doSomethingToServer(server);
            success = true;
        } catch (RuntimeException | IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            if (failureException == null)
                failureException = e;
            else
                failureException.addSuppressed(e);
        }
    }
    if (! success && failureException != null) {
        if (failureException instanceof RuntimeException)
            throw (RuntimeException) failureException;
        if (failureException instanceof IOException)
            throw (IOException) failureException;
        if (failureException instanceof GeneralSecurityException)
            throw (GeneralSecurityException) failureException;
        throw new RuntimeException("Oops! Unexpected exception type: " + failureException, failureException);
    }
}

private void doSomethingToServer(Server server) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // code here
}
```